# How does the auto format of the join command work?

Tags: join, documentation

Here is an example:

```
$ cat file1
hello
there
$ cat file2
some,very,long,line,hello,csv
some,very,long,line,nope,csv
$ join -t, -1 1 -2 5 file1 file2
hello,some,very,long,line,csv
```

This works as documented: the joined field is pulled out to the left, and the remaining fields are printed.

But my desired output is to retain the CSV (file2) column ordering. 
I can get to print the CSV intact with this command,
which lists the CSV field numbers explicitly:

```
join -t, -1 1 -2 5 -o $(head -n1 file2 | awk -F, '{print NF}' | xargs seq | sed 's/^/2./' | paste -d, -s) file1 file2
```

And it prints:

```
some,very,long,line,hello,csv
```

I *thought* it's for this that `join` has an `auto` format. This is the precious little the man page of `join` has to say about the `-o FORMAT`:

> If FORMAT is the keyword 'auto', then the first line of each file determines the number of fields output for each line.

However, I don't know what that means
or how I'm supposed to use the format as `auto`.

I tried this, but didn't get anything different than I did previously:

```
$ join -t, -1 1 -2 5 -o auto file1 file2
hello,some,very,long,line,csv
```

A naive interpretation would be that I should list out the required fields as the first line of each file, but that's wrong, too.

So, my question is, what is the `auto` for, and how am I supposed to use it? Can I use it to retain the column order of the input CSV?

Comment: Run `info coreutils join invocation`... it's explained better there... and no, you can't use it to retain the column order.

Comment: The relevant paragraph from the `info` page is: If the keyword ‘auto’ is specified, infer the output format from
     the first line in each file.  This is the same as the default
     output format but also ensures the same number of fields are output
     for each line.  Missing fields are replaced with the ‘-e’ option
     and extra fields are discarded.

Comment: @don_crissti, obligatory [info page XKCD](https://xkcd.com/912/). I'm wondering what the rationale is for `join` to mess with the field ordering in the default case. IOW, what would happen if `join` were not to list the join field as the first column? In my case, it's too much hassle to filter a CSV without messing up its presentation.

Comment: Why do you say that `join` "messes" with the filed ordering? It doesn't. It says clearly in the docs that `each output line consists of the join field, the remaining fields from FILE1, then the remaining fields from FILE2`. In your particular case, FILE1 has only one column - so you only get the join field and the remaining fields from FILE2. Try with a two-column file and you'll see the difference. If you want to output only the lines from FILE2 and retain the order you'll have to specify it via `-o` e.g. ` join -t, -o 2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7...`

Comment: No, I wasn't saying `join` wasn't behaving like how was documented. My question was _why_ it was designed to work that way. It'd be beyond surprising if `grep` were to mess up the word order on the matched lines. Likewise, I'd expect `join`'s default behaviour to retain the field ordering of the input files. IOW, the output should have been as how `paste f1 f2` would have output, but only matching lines. That way, I could have used `cut` to recover from `join`'s output the respective lines from input files (using `cut -d N-M` syntax) in their original order, without needing to specify `-o`.

Comment: You probably don't work with databases/SQL... `join` is a relational database operator. Why should it behave like `grep`/`paste` which are text processing tools? If you want a different output use the `-o` switch. Or use `awk` or maybe `csvjoin` from `csvkit`...

Comment: DB column order is an implementation detail, but most implementations will retain the defined column order when presenting results. Like `grep`, what `join` is effectively doing is row filtering. I find it [surprising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) that it does/has to do column reordering, unless this very specific default behaviour somehow aids faster implementation, or this presentation has proven _very_ useful. IOW, if I were tasked with implementing `join`, my first thought won't be, 'yeah, let me pull out the join field all the way to the left'.